# How to enable CSS position: sticky in mobile browsers?

Tags: css, css-position, mobile-browser

Added some `position: sticky` property to my webpage. On Desktop browser work fine but sucks in mobiles.

Comment: which browser and which version are you testing?

Comment: Safari ios10 and chrome for ios

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`sticky` property for Chrome and Safari for iOS needs to be set with `-webkit` vendor first:

```
.element {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
}
```

You can check about browser compatibility in [canIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky)