# Overflow: auto is not working as it should

Tags: css, overflow

I want this page to have a fixed top and a bottom that will fill the remaining viewport.  The bottom will be used to display jpg's.  When the jpg's are too big I want scroll bars to appear only in the bottom section.  I have tried every combination I think of fixed & absolute for the 3 divs and none have given me the functionality I'm looking for.  The code below shows the horizontal scroll bar when needed but not the vertical.  Any help would be great.  Here's what I have:

```
<body>

    <style>
    
            body
            {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
            }
    
            #Top
            {
                position: fixed;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                height: 200px;
                width: 100px;
                background: red;
            }
            
            #Bottom
            {
                position: fixed;
                top: 200px;
                width: 100%;
                background: green;
                overflow: auto;                 
            }
            
            #Content
            {
                width:100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: purple; 
                overflow: auto;                 
            }
            
    </style>

<body>
    <div id="Top">
    </div>
    
    <div id="Bottom">
        <div id="Content">
            <!-- This is just a blue box that should cause scroll 
            bars to appear when the viewport is resized too small.-->
            <img src="Blue500x1000.jpg">  
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

Comment: Try it "position:sticky" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249771/how-to-enable-css-position-sticky-in-mobile-browsers

Comment: @Alan: Hi There ! Right now your top looks like a side bar :) Could you share your desired output image?

Comment: I think that you have to have fixed height instead of using percentage though

Comment: You can use either flexbox or grid layout.

Comment: You won't get vertical scrolling in an element without a height.